# Export specific columns in p-datatable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I want to export specific columns in p-datatable. I have export all records before, but now I want to export specific columns. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

From [PrimeNG doc](http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable)

> In order to exclude a column from the csv, use `[exportable]="false"` on `p-column`.

Answer (score 0):

For getting a specific column there is one solution.
Html Page:

```
<p-dataTable #dg [value]="groupdetails" selectionMode="multiple" resizableColumns="true" reorderableColumns="true"  expandableRows="true" [paginator]="true" [rows]="5" [pageLinks]="3" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]" [loading]="ploader3">
     <p-header>
        <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" (click)="dg.exportCSV({selectionOnly:true})" style="float:left"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> SELECTED EXPORT</button>
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" (click)="export(dg)" style="float:right"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i> Export</button>
        </div>
     </p-header>
     <p-column field="groupName" [filter]="true" [sortable]="true" header="groupName"></p-column>
     <p-column field="groupId" [filter]="true" [sortable]="true" header="groupId"></p-column>
     <p-column field="parentGroupId" [filter]="true" [sortable]="true" header="parentGroupId"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

In Ts page:

```
public export(e){ 
 const hiddenColumns: any[] = [];
 e.columns.forEach((c) => {
  if (c.field === "hiddencolumnName" ) {
    hiddenColumns.push({field: c.field, col: c});
    c.field = '';
  } if (c.field === "hiddencolumnName2" ) {
    hiddenColumns.push({field: c.field, col: c});
    c.field = '';
  } 
}
e.exportCSV();
// restore their fields so still works in the future
hiddenColumns.forEach((hc) => {
  hc.col.field = hc.field;
});
}
```

Add columns to a hidden array which you don't want to export.